# kthread_run returns ENOMEM

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I am using Realtek Wi-Fi driver rtl8192du in Linux kernel 3.10.53. Many of the APIs used in the driver were deprecated and thrown compile time error. I replace the API s and now the driver is being registered when the kernel boots. But the interface wlan0 is down. When I make the interface up ,it shows that the kthread_run is returning ENOMEM . The code snippet is below

```
 u32 rtw_start_drv_threads(_adapter *padapter)
{
----------
----------
padapter->cmdThread = kthread_run(rtw_cmd_thread, padapter, "RTW_CMD_THREAD");
 if(padapter->cmdThread < 0)
_status = _FAIL;
else
_rtw_down_sema(&padapter->cmdpriv.terminate_cmdthread_sema);

}
```

Is there any way to avoid kthread_run returning ENOMEM error so that the ifconfig wlan0 up is successful?

Comment: That's not the way to adapt the driver to the kernel. The way to do it is to install backports.

Comment: I downloaded the latest RTL8192DU driver from the Realtek Website. But the driver also has used kernel_thread instead of kthread_run ,which again throws compilation error against Linux kernel 3.10.53.May be I need to dig again for the RTL8192DU driver compatible with 3.10.53 kernel

Comment: Backports are meant to be old driver with new API's...right?  I have the old version of rtl8192du usb driver and newest Linux kernel,which cause the compatible mess

Comment: No, backports are supposed to be new drivers for old kernels. You have a very old kernel,  3.10. It may be new for the version of the distro you are running, but it is very old. LTS Ubuntu 14.04 uses 3.16, current newset stable kernel is 4.2

Comment: Okay. Actually I am building the realtek Wi-Fi driver for Android Lollipop with kernel version 3.10.53 for my target board. Instead of replacing the kthread_run, I used the kernel_thread() only, and added it as an EXPORT_SYMBOL in the kernel fork.c file. The compilation error due to kernel_thread is solved and insmod is working. But again "Segmentation fault "  is occuring when I make ifconfig wlan0 up :(

Comment: Like I said, try backports, here http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/  Otherwise, try `strace` to debug your driver.

Comment: I used the strace to debug the driver when the ifconfig wlan0 up command is issued. The output is  provided in the pastebin link http://pastebin.com/sYfS8w4y . I could not find any peculiar reason for the segmentation fault...Or Have I missed out something?